# Concerns about the definition of Hawkes process

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, point-processes, random-measures

In the lecture notes I am reading about Point process, when we introduced the Hawkes process several expressions are given and I have some difficulty to understand properly what is the $Z_t$ (defined below). I tried to make my doubts clear by precising two points w of concerns.

Before I introduce the framework in order to fix notations.

We consider $T_1<…<T_n<..$ the sequence of jump event with values in $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$ and $\lambda(t)$ the intensity function at time $t$. We define the poisson random measure (PRM) associated to the sequence of jump event by

$$
M(\omega)(A)= \sum_{i\geq 0}\delta_{T_i(\omega)}(A),\quad A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{2})
$$

I will skip the $\omega$ in the sequel for the PRM. Now we define the set

$$
A_t = \{ (x_1,x_2) : 0\leq x_1\leq t, 0\leq x_2\leq\lambda(x_1)\}
$$

By precising that $\lambda(t) = \mu + \sum_{n : T_n <t}h(t-T_n)$ with $\mu>0$ and $h :\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$, we define the linear Hawkes process by

$$
Z_t = M(A_t) 
$$

Then, I have two concerns :

- The justification of such equality

$Z_t = \int_{[0,t]}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{z\leq\lambda(s)} M(ds,dz)$

Indeed,I would like to start with the very definition of $Z_t$ that is with an integral over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ since the PRM is a $2$ dimensional random measure :

$$
Z_t = \int_{[0,t]\times[0,\lambda(s)]}M(ds,dz)
$$

But then I don’t know how to separate the integral in two since I cannot use Fubini in this context.

How can I justify the passage from the integral above to

$$
Z_t = \int_{[0,t]}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{z\leq\lambda(s)} M(ds,dz)
$$

?

This makes me doubt about my comprehension of this $Z_t$.

- The second concern is about the function $\lambda(t)$. Indeed $h$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ so the expression $h(t-T_n)$ does not make sense since $T_n(\omega)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$ ?

This concerns me all the more as the following expression is often used

$$
\int_{(0,s)}h(s-u)dZ_u = \sum_{ k : T_k < s} h(s-T_k)
$$

Which, for me until now, does not make sense given the definition of $T_n$.

If you have any answers that might help me, please don't hesitate! Thank you very much.

---

$\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2} = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} : x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$

---

After some thoughts concerning the second point, it may be possible to consider as the initial point process $X_k$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$ (for example a $2$ dimensional uniform law) and then define

$$
T_k(\omega)= \pi_{1}(X_k(\omega))= x_1
$$

Where $X_k(\omega)=(x_1,x_2)$. In order to have

$$
\lambda(t) = \mu + \sum_{n : T_n <t}h(t-T_n)
$$

that is well defined.

I don’t know if it is correct in that way but I think it avoids the confusion I highlighted above. Let me know what is your thoughts on this please.

Comment: $M$ is a random measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it's a sum of dirac measures $\delta_{T_i}$ with $T_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The $T_i$ have values in $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$ and I think that it is in order  to make sense of $\delta_{T_i}(A)$ since $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$

Comment: But as you point out you also need to make sense of $\sum_{T_n< t} h(t-T_n)$ which requires that $T_n \in \mathbb{R}$. A quick glance at the wikipedia definition my guess is $T_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and you're missing something in the definition of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, applying Fubini shouldn't be an issue here: Note that, as you already described in your post, a Point Process is a *random measure*. Hence for any event $\omega$ the value $M(\omega)$ is a measure. Now the associated Hawkes Process reads $$M(A_t)(\omega)=\int 1_{A_t} dM(\omega)$$ Since the constant $1_{A_t}$ obviously is non-negative and the Point Process is defined on the product-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb B(\mathbb R^2_+)$, we can apply Fubini $\omega$-wise to obtain $$M(A_t)(\omega)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty 1_{A_t}((x,y)) M(\omega)(dx,dy)=\int_0^t\int_0^{\lambda(s)}dM(\omega).$$ Hence the equality you described above holds for every $\omega$.

To the second point: As @Michh already mentioned, there seem to be different definitions of the Hawkes Process in the literature, either based on univariate Point Processes (as in [mathworld.wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HawkesProcess.html)) or based on multivariate Point Processes, as you are doing in your post. The mathworld post also includes the expression you mentioned (see Eq. (2)), though their time points are 1-dimensional.

Regarding your setup: You suppose that $T_1<T_2<\dots<T_k$ are points in $\mathbb R^2_+$, but what does $T_i<T_{i+1}$ mean if the $T_i$ are multivariate? Component-wise inequality? You seem to be mixing up the two approaches here, but here is a connection between the "multivariate approach" and the "univariate approach":

Let $\lambda$ be an intensity function and let $N_t$ be an *inhomogeneous* Poisson Process with intensity $\lambda$, meaning $$\mathbb EN_t=\int_0^t\lambda(s)ds.$$
I will show how to construct this *inhomogenous* Poisson Process using a *homogeneous* Poisson Process. Let $\mathcal P$ be a homogeneous Poisson Point Process on $\mathbb R^2_+$, meaning the intensity measure of $\mathcal P$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then construct the set $A_t$ as you did: $$A_t:=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2_+: x_1\leq t, x_2\leq \lambda(x_1)\}$$ and we see by Fubini that $$\mathbb E\big[\mathcal P(A_t)\big]=\int_0^t\int_0^{\lambda(s)}1 dz ds = \int_0^t\lambda(s)ds.$$
Thus $\mathcal P(A_t)$ has the same law as $N_t$. This argument can be repeated for general time intervals, showing that the laws of $(\mathcal P(A_t))_{t\geq 0}$ and $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ coincide.

Now the "one-dimensional appproach" is to construct an *inhomogenous* Poisson Process $N_t$ with conditional intensity $$\lambda(t):=\mu+\sum_{T_k<t}h(t-T_k)$$ where the time points $T_k$ are **one-dimensional**. The "multivariate approach" would be to consider a homogenous Poisson Point Process $\mathcal P$ as described above, then defining $M_t=\mathcal P(A_t)$. Note that the arguments given above still work for *conditional* intensities $\lambda$, since if $\mathcal F_t$ is the filtration up to time $t$, we have $$\frac{1}{h}\mathbb E\bigg[\mathcal P(A_{t+h})-\mathcal P(A_t)\big|\mathcal F_t\bigg]=\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h}\int_0^{\lambda(s)}dzds=\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h}\lambda(s)ds\to \lambda(t)$$ as $h\to 0$. Hence $\mathcal P(A_t)$ has the same conditional intensity as $N_t$. Since, under certain assumptions, the conditional intensity uniquely determines (the law of) a Poisson Process, we again get that the laws of $(\mathcal P(A_t))_{t\geq 0}$ and $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ coincide. For a reference, see [these lecture notes, Proposition 2.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00221.pdf).

I hope my answer was somewhat helpful. Please correct me if you notice any mistakes!

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time to answer my concerns. The construction is clear and I think that the principal confusion was from a misunderstanding of the notations used in my lectures (making the function $h$ not well defined). Concerning the $T_i$, in the update I have defined them as the canonical projection (of a $2$ dimensional point process) over the $x$ axis in order to avoid this difficulty, it is unusual and not necessary when things are clear. Thank you a lot !